# Expandable CSS div not working in iOS 8

Tags: html, ios, css, expand

I've got some expandable/collapsible divs that are working fine on desktop computers (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE). They also work fine in Chrome for Android on a mobile device.

However, the divs don't expand in any browser on iOS 8. Clicking on the headers will change the color and switch the icon, so I know the toggle box is working, but the div doesn't become visible.

Here is the CSS that controls the div expansion:

```
.toggle-box + label + div {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.toggle-box:checked + label + div {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://cmckenzie6.github.io/ColinMcKenzie/expandable.html).
Here is the [full code](http://cmckenzie6.github.io/ColinMcKenzie/expandable.txt).

I suppose I could use jQuery mobile as an alternative but I would prefer not to use any external libraries if possible.

Comment: Using chrome emulator they appear to be fine, could you possibly provide some screenshots so we could theorise what could potentially be wrong?

Comment: @jaunt it doesn't work on my phone.  Possibly related to the display:none (stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property), but I'm not sure why that would work on desktops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're abusing the adjacent sibling selector. I took a look at the spec, and between using three selectors as well as a pseudo-element, you're pushing your luck.

Fortunately, you can use the plain old sibling selector: `~`

eg:

```
.toggle-box ~ div {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.toggle-box:checked ~ div {
    display: block;
}
```

In which case you'll need to wrap each toggle to prevent the all the boxes being toggled by one input. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0defj7yc/1/

Comment: Came here after pulling my hair out for hours, iOS8 definitely doesn't like pseudo selectors in conjunction with multiple adjacent sibling selectors. Great spot!